# What are the content differences between the 70mm 'Roadshow' print, and the wide distribution digital release?

Tags: the-hateful-eight

*The Hateful Eight* is being released in two formats. Currently, a 70mm "Roadshow" edition is screening in limited theatres, and in a week, a *different cut* of the film is being released to wide distribution as a digital film.

I understand [the differences with respect to the aspect ratio and film format between the two versions,](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45424/49) and am not interested in those (nor, save for the sake of completeness, the presence of a printed program, an Overture and Intermission in the Roadshow screenings.)

However, the Roadshow edition of the film is also *longer* (I've seen conflicting numbers, but the most commonly cited are 6 and 20 minutes longer - I suspect the latter number includes the overture).

What I'm curious about is what, if any, are the specific narrative and dramatic differences between the two versions of the film? I find it hard to believe that you'd get even six more minutes just lingering on landscapes in a film that is as entirely interior as *The Hateful Eight*.

Comment: Related: [What exactly is 70mm print and why does anyone care?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/45424/49)

Answer (score 3):

There's a scene where John Ruth tells the Bob the Mexican to go pluck the chicken in the 70mm print, but it's not in the digital edition. I didn't realize it until later when Bob was finishing plucking, realized they cut an entire encounter between those two.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the roadshow, just the screener online (that's is of course the digital normal version) but on the web I've found:

> I noticed the copy online [...] there are subtle differences, like when daisy is playing guitar, she misses a chord but keeps playing on the 70mm version, but the digital they used a take where she didn't miss the chord. The ending was a little different too.

Nothing more... I'm also really curious (because in Italy will be out on Febrary and just one movie theater with 70mm version!). Probably on the DVD we'll have all the answers! Yesterday I've seen it again and, just for the sake of foretelling, adding 10 sec for every "natural big landscape frame" you add at least 4 minutes of movie...

Comment: Since you "found that on the web", it might be interesting *where* you found that.